# Wiremock dynamic verify queryParam

Tags: mocking, wiremock

I have some BDD tests, that checks the query parameters of a callback with Wiremock.
So, the problem is that verification fails when i build the RequestPatternBuilder dynamic.

More details :
I have a map with the desired key/value pairs of the query parameter, and i want to iterate over it, in order to build the RequestPatternBuilder object.
Here is the algorithm:

```
        RequestPatternBuilder patternBuilder = getRequestedFor(callbackUrlPath);
        
        parameterMap.forEach(
                (k, v) -> patternBuilder.withQueryParam(k, equalTo(v)));

        CommonUtils.waitFor(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5);

        verify(patternBuilder);
```

The verification fails with the following message:

```
GET
/callback?testParam1=value1&testParam2=value2&testParam3=value4

testParam1: value1
Query: testParam2 = value2
Query: testParam3 = value3
> but was:<
GET
//callback?testParam1=value1&testParam2=value2&testParam3=value4

testParam1: value1
```

The weird thing though, is that if i change the algorithm and adding queryParam, as follows:
`getRequestedFor(callbackUrlPath).withQueryParam("testParam1", equalTo(value1)).withQueryParam("testParam2", equalTo(value2)).withQueryParam("testParam3", equalTo(value3))`, verification pass.

Any idea??

Comment: Can you add your `parameterMap` object? My guess is that when you're doing your `forEach`, it doesn't addend the `.withQueryParam()` method, but replaces the existing. My Java is a little rusty, but have you tried `... -> patternBuilder = patternBuilder.withQueryParam(k, equalTo(v))...` ?

Comment: ParameterMao is a simple key/value map with strings, nothing more nothing less. Doesn't compile if you put the assignment operator in lamba expression, I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
the issue was that parameter had changed from testParam2 to testparam2, and i didn't see it. The error that propagated, was describe that was not possible to find a match url, and that is true, because the code expect `testParam2` and was `testparam2`
I updated and all worked perfectly